# Usage of [mat-dialog-close]

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am a bit confused about the usage of [mat-dialog-close].

So, I have a dialog with a form. If the user clicks the submit button, the form is validated. If the input is valid, the dialog is closed and the form is submitted. However, if the input is invalid, the dialog remains opened and an error message is shown. For that I want to use [mat-dialog-close] as it is described in the [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content) where it is used as follows:

```
<button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true">Yes</button>
```

I thought that I can just pass it a boolean and whether the tag is active depends on the boolean value of the variable. However, this does not work. I tried it like this:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="addUser()" [mat-dialog-close]="formisvalid" mat-button>Submit</button>
```

I passed it the variable `formisvalid`. It's value is `true` unless the input is invalid. But now the dialog closes always, regardless of the value of `formisvalid`.
I also tried replacing it with `false`. I thought the dialog would remain opened no matter what happens, but it would also always close.

So, my question is: am I mistaken about the use of [mat-dialog-close] or am I just doing something wrong? If this is not achievable with the [mat-dialog-close] directive, what would be another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Don't use it with [].
Ex.: `<button mat-dialog-close>*Your text*</button>`

Comment: But why would they implement it then, if I'm not supposed to use it? There has to be a use for it, doesn't it?

Comment: What do you mean? You import it in your component and app.module.ts, and then you call the button in the HTML component as in my example

Comment: Yes, this works, but not as I want it to. If I do it like you described, then the dialog will close always when I press the save button. I want it to only close when the form is valid, otherwise it is supposed to stay opened.

Comment: Import the MatDialogRef class and in the constructor: `public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YOURDIALOGCOMPONENT>,`. Then call dialogRef.afterClose(*somecode*).

Comment: Set an if-statement that checks if the form is valid f.ex if(form.value === 'VALID')..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Set your button to have disabled on it if the form is not valid.  This way the button cannot be clicked unless the form is valid, meaning it won't close unless the form is valid

```
<button type="submit" (click)="addUser()" mat-dialog-close [disabled]="formisvalid" mat-button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: it is some workaround, but can I easily close dialog from inside the dialog component. I have httpClient request in onSubmit method and I would like to close or not the dialog depending on the result. If I have the successful result in subscribe method I will close the dialog. Otherwise I will leave it with some warning message displayed.

Comment: yeah, you would have `constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<YourDialog>) { }` on your constructor, and then just `this.dialogRef.close(returnValue);`

Answer (score 26):

Just to make the answer complete: `mat-dialog-close` will close your dialog if it's clicked, no matter what value you assign to it. If you want to control whether clicking it will close the dialog, use `[disabled]="formisvalid"` as [other answer] states.

However the value assigned to `mat-dialog-close` is not ignored. It's interpreted as the dialog *result* value, and as such can be read by the component that opened the dialog, by subscribing to `dialogRef.afterClosed()`. This behaviour is explained in the official documentation:

- https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content
- https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogClose
- https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogRef

Answer (score 10):

Since this caused confusion for a lot of developers: if you want to perform requests on close and/or trigger the close with a custom element (instead of a basic button), you can inject a reference to the dialog and then call `.close`:

`constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) { }` - replace DialogComponent with your component name

Then define a method on your component class and call it in your template:

```
async closeDialog() {
    try {
      await someAsyncThing();
      this.dialogRef.close(); // make sure it only closes if the upper async fn succesfully ran!
    } catch(e) {
      this.errorMessage = e.response.message;
    }
}
```

`<fancy-ass-close-item (click)="closeDialog()"/>`

As opposed to other answers here, this enables you to call requests before closing the dialog (and thus display an error message or something inside the dialog).

Answer (score 8):

uses of mat-dialog-close(applicable for dialog)

1.to prevents accidental form submits.

```html
<form #queryForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveQuery()">
    <button mat-button (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
    <!--ended up by submitting the form instead of calling close function, -->
    <!--So you should add mat-dialog-close to prevent it-->
<form>
```

2.to close dialog.

```html
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close>close</button>
<!--closes dialog even without explicit function-->
```

3.to return data.

```html
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close="myData">close</button>
```

Add to the component:

```js
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data=>{
    console.log("data returned from mat-dialog-close is ",data);
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Here you can pass any number of values as a array to an attribute [mat-dialog-close]

```
<button [mat-dialog-close]="[organizationId,costCenterId,partnerDepartmentId]" cdkFocusInitial class="iport_primary_btn"mat-raised-button>Go</button>
```

In parent component you can subscribe to the result after closing dialog like below

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***mat-dialog-close* directive only works with button element and not any other one.**

Comment: this is not true, I've tried it on other element and it worked well

Comment: [Dox](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content) says "mat-dialog-close  [Attr] Added to a <button>, makes the button close the dialog with an optional result from the bound value." which can be read as, *per specification*, *only* button or *for instance* button.

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<OffersComponent>
  ) {}
```

and right it down close() function where u want to close the ur dialog box

```
 this.dialogRef.close();
```