# Closing MatDialogRef in Electron

Tags: angular, electron

I am working on an Angular 5 app compiled through Electron 2.0.5. I am using  `MatDialogRef` to get user input (`Yes` or `No`) and using the response to govern some business logic. After displaying the `MatDialogRef`, I cannot get it to close.

The HTML of the dialog ref: confirm.component.html

```
<div class="confirm">
  <h1 mat-dialog-title>Confirm</h1>

  <div mat-dialog-content>
    {{dialogData.message}}
  </div>

  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="'cancel'" (click)="close()">No</button>
    <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="'yes'" cdkFocusInitial (click)="close()">Yes</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

The logic: confirm.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirm',
  templateUrl: './confirm.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirm.component.scss']
})
export class ConfirmComponent implements OnInit {

  dialogData: any;

  constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any) {
      this.dialogData = data;
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

And finally on my app.ts:

```
...
    const dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(ConfirmComponent, {
        data: {
            message: 'Yes or No?'
        }
    });

    return dialogRef.afterClosed()
        .switchMap(result => {
            if (result !== 'cancel') {
                // Do something
            } else {
                // Do something
            }
        });
...
```

When debugging the app through VSCode I can confirm the close() method is being hit. The dialog does not close and there are no console errors. How do I close the mat dialog ref?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47592364/usage-of-mat-dialog-close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, your code is missing the subscription:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
});
```

Replace the `switchMap` by `subscribe`

See docs example here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content

---

By the way, you can use this alternative, without the `mat-dialog-close` directive:

See https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/ (Step 5)

You can pass the modified form data back to AppComponent in the following way:

```
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="close(false)">No</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="close(true)">Yes</button>
  </div>
```

and

```
  close(clickResult: boolean): void {
    this.matDialogRef.close(clickResult);
  }
```

You can now receive the dialog data in the following way:

```
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
    data => console.log("Dialog output:", data)
);
```